# Problem with elapsed time using MPI_Wtime

Tags: c, performance, time, parallel-processing, mpi

I need to calculate the time between the execution of this code, **as it is only done from rank 0**, regardless of the number of total ranks, I don't understand why the **results** given by the difference of the start time and the end time, **grows as the rank increases**.

```c
if(world_rank ==0){
        output = (int *)calloc(n, sizeof(int));


        start_time1 = MPI_Wtime();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            output[count[arr[i]] - 1] = arr[i];
            count[arr[i]]--;
        }
        end_time1 = MPI_Wtime();
    }
```

The **value** given by the **difference** between **start_time** and **end_time** **grows** as the total number of ranks increases, despite the fact that this operation is only ever done from rank 0.

Comment: Assuming `n` is independent from the number of ranks, that can happen if the other ranks are spinning when rank `0` performs its job. That can cause rank `0` to lose the benefit of turbo mode, and/or sub optimal pinning can cause process migration, and hence lower performances.

Comment: I can confirm that n is independent of the number of processes. Is there any way to give the highest priority to rank 0?